# Building angularfire2 for ionic2

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I have been trying to build the [sample app](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic2-angularfire-sample) with the following steps

`npm install 
ionic build`

I get the following error

`TypeScript error: C:/Users/Manu/impronto/ionic2-angularfire-sample/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth.d.ts(12,20): Error TS1112: A class member cannot be declared optional.
TypeScript error: C:/Users/Manu/impronto/ionic2-angularfire-sample/node_modules/angularfire2/utils/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(6,17): Error TS1112: A class member cannot be declared optional.`

Now, I think that the errors are in angularfire2. However, I cannot help wonder how you were able to build the application on your PC. I am new to the entire ecosystem. I have not changed any codebase.

I looked a bit into the code

`auth.d.ts has     private _config?; //? being optional 
firebase_object_observable has private _ref?; //`

Is it worth raising bug at the angularfire2 repository? Is it possible to get some suggestions on workaround for now?